# Best way to process many objects?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, thrift, impala, parquet

I would like to store many objects and afterwards to process them. ( to do statistics using data )

Now, what I have done :

> - I have serialized with Thrift one object each file. (1 thrift object = 1 binary file)
> - I also convert the thrift object to a Parquet file. (I'm suprised because my thrift binary file does about 1 KB while the parquet file does 140 KB for the same data !)

Then, for you, what is the best way ?

> 1) Use Parquet file with Impala ?
>
> 2) Use Thrift files with ..I don't know.. ? ( and how to serialize many object in the same file to have more sized file, I read files have to very big to be efficient )
>
> 3) Pig ? Hive ? with .. ?
>
> 4) ... ?

I want to use HDFS to store my files.

I use Ruby to create Thrift file and I use Java to convert it to Parquet file.

Is it compulsory to use MapReduce ? Can I use it later ?

Thank you !

Comment: The Thrift binary format is an efficient storage format, designed with performance efficiency in mind. Therefore, it is "only" the plain data. For some languages there's compression support (gzip IIRC) available, but not for all. From what I did read on the paquet web site, they store stuff compressed by default, which may explain the difference in size. Additionally, paquet seems to have a Thrift layer already in place.

Comment: Yes but I can't use directly my Thrift files with Impala/Pig etc...
I have to find a way to serialize many objects in one Thrift file.
Because schema is at each time written in Parquet file...

Comment: What exactly prevents you from doing that? What exactly is the problem? Have you tried a `struct` and/or a `list<>` to hold multiple objects?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to do a list<> of my main object.
But it's very difficult to find a simple example to use my Thrift/Parquet files.
Even if what I would like to do is very simple:
Store my Thrift/Parquet files into HDFS and process them with Pig/Hive/Impala etc...